# How to align more than one <img> inside a <div>?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align this 6 images iside a div, but the CSS make then aligned, but they know are in a vertical line, but I want them side-by-side
[image: Desired result]

```css
div#menu-lixos img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="linha-laranja" class="linha-laranja">
        <h1 class="titulo">Materiais Recicláveis</h1>
        <h2 class="titulo2">histórias e propriedades</h2>
        <div id="menu-lixos" class="menu-lixos">
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you said you want `them side-by-side`. what are you trying to do ? you want them vertically center ?

Comment: You set them to display:block, why? Also, IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the CSS property display:flex to .menu-lixos. This will line up its child elements in a row. And then you can you can add some subsequent CSS properties to .menu-lixos — such as justify-content and align-items — to get the spacing right.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display: flex;` to the container, and then setting the `flex` "settings" to what you want:

```css
#linha-laranja #menu-lixos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="linha-laranja" class="linha-laranja">
        <h1 class="titulo">Materiais Recicláveis</h1>
        <h2 class="titulo2">histórias e propriedades</h2>
        <div id="menu-lixos" class="menu-lixos">
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
            <img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can then add `justify-content` and `align-items` properties to get the spacing correct. Hope this works for you!

Comment: thanks man!!
but I just added a text-align:center; and this solved my problem LOL